# React Component errors (Input)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[SOLVED]
Solution was: 1) the 'extends React.Component' doesn't autoBind any more.
2) 'filterText' variable needed to be sended 'handleUserInput(filterText)'...

Thank you for All!!

Good day.
This code is working on "React.createClass" and now I'm trying to change it to "extends React.Component".
The aim is to sort the elements by entering value into input.

The **code**:

```
TheSecondComponent...
constructor(props){
super(props);
}
handleChange() {
this.props.onUserInput(
  this.refs.filterTextInput.value
);
}
render() {
return (
  <form className='Center'>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={this.props.filterText}
      ref="filterTextInput"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  </form>
);
}

 TheFirstComponent...
 constructor(){
 super();
 this.state={'filterText': ''} // If to use setState here than I have one 
                               more error, added in the end of the question
 this.handleUserInput=this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
 }
 getInitialState() {
 return {
  filterText: ''
 };
 }
 handleUserInput(filterText) {
 //this.setState({filterText: filterText});
 this.state = {filterText: filterText};
 }
 render() {
  return (
  <div>
  <div>
    <SearchBar
      filterText={this.state.filterText}
      onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
    />
    <CreateButtons
      source={this.props.citys}
      filterText={this.state.filterText}
    />
  </div>
  </div>
  );
  }
```

The **WORKING** code of the "React.createClass":

```
TheFirstComponent...
({
handleChange: function() {
this.props.onUserInput(
  this.refs.filterTextInput.value
 );
 },
 render: function() {
  return (
  <form className='Center'>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={this.props.filterText}
      ref="filterTextInput"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  </form>
   );
  }
  });

   TheSecondComponent...
   ({
   getInitialState: function() {
   return {
   filterText: ''
    };
    },
    handleUserInput: function(filterText) {
   this.setState({
   filterText: filterText
   });
   },
   render: function() {cl(this);
   return (
  <div>
  <div className='SLFirst'>
    <SearchBar
      filterText={this.state.filterText}
      onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
    />
    <CreateButtons
      source={this.props.citys}
      filterText={this.state.filterText}
    />
    </div>
    </div>
     );
    } 
    });
```

Have an error:
I am trying to input any text in the "input" but it doesn't write the value. I mean, I am typing, but nothing changes. is it because of

`this.state={'filterText': ''}` ?

And how should I play with it? If to set not '' but 'sometext' then this 'sometext' will be unchangable.

As I found "setState" is no longer working.
And if to use 'setState' then have oooone more:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'filterText' of null
   40 | <div>
   41 | <div className='SLFirst'>
   42 |   <SearchBar
 > 43 |     filterText={this.state.filterText}
   44 |     onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
   45 |   />
   46 |   <CreateButtons
```

Comment: `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}` es6 class needs to bind context

Comment: thank you for reply. Have a new error. Just sec, will past it in the question

Comment: `onUserInput={this.handleUserInput.bind(this)}` or better use arrow functions everywhere.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi Sorry, yes, I'v done it. And I have this situation with binded function. Please, see edited question

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind the *handleChange()*.
 To fix this problem you have to bind the methods  which are using "this" in constructor(). Try the following code

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}

handleChange() {
 this.props.onUserInput(
 this.refs.filterTextInput.value
);
}
render() {
 return (
   <form className='Center'>
       <input
         type="text"
         value={this.props.filterText}
         ref="filterTextInput"
         onChange={this.handleChange}
   />
   </form>
       );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Done, passed, but have another error... Just sec, will past it in the question

Answer (score 0):

this.state = {...} will not trigger a re-render,
to update your state use the **setState** function

setState can take either an object

```
  //the following will update the filterText property on the state object
  this.setState({filterText: ''})
```

or a function

```
this.setState(function(state){
    state.filterText = '';
    // make sure you return state
    return state
})
```

make sure you initialize your state object in your constructor as follows

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      filterText: 'initiale value'
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you. If I use 'setState' as you suggest I have one more error (why I have so much errors?!) Added in the end of the question...

Comment: i updated my answer, just make sure you go through the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/

Comment: I did, and there were written that "setState" no more works. just "state". and If I use "state" then input does not update value while entering.

Comment: for exampe, I used your code with "initiale value" and input has constant-like value 'initiale value' and typing doesn't change it